# Using Filter Query in Graph API to fetch the particular users

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

Current code:

```
public render(): void {
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
.then((graphclient:MSGraphClient): void=>{
  graphclient
  .api('/users')
  .filter('Department eq IT')
  .get((error,user:MicrosoftGraph.User,rawResponse?:any)=>{
    console.log(user)
 }
```

Fetching users detail through Graph API call and filtering users for a particular Department into web part in SPFx.

Using No JavaScript framework to build this web part.

When not using filter, getting all the users details.

How to use filter in the API call?

Comment: Try below filter queries. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using filter like below:

```
.filter("Department eq 'IT'")
```

OR

```
.filter("department eq 'IT'")
```

**Update**

It is working fine for me:

[image]

Endpoint used:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=Department eq 'Finance'&$select=id,displayName,department
```

Try giving below permissions:

- User.ReadBasic.All
- User.Read.All

[image]

Comment: I had tried both the way but not working

Comment: error: {code: "Authorization_RequestDenied", message: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",…}

Comment: Check updated answer. try with `User.ReadBasic.All` and `User.Read.All` permissions.

Comment: I am getting the same user data when calling API through graph explorer
but when calling the API through code ,getting a error in the console


error: {code: "Authorization_RequestDenied", message: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",…}

Comment: Is this issue resolved or you still facing any problem with this?